# iPhone SDK - NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable / appendBytes: crashing

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

Disclaimer: I am an Xcode / iPhone SDK Noob.

I am trying to establish a client-side TCP/IP connection to an existing server. Upon connection, I expect to receive some data about the server (version, etc.).

When my connection is made, the `NSStreamEventOpenCompleted` event fires, so I know the connection is made. Next the `NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable` event fires and I am executing the following code. The value 71 (int) is stored in len, which I believe is correct. However, the line

```
[data appendBytes:&buffer length:len];
```

is crashing (I think). There is no actual error thrown but I do see  **`__TERMINATING_DUE_TO_UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTION__`** even though I have clearly added error catching:

```
case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
    {
        NSMutableData *data=[[NSMutableData alloc] init];

        uint8_t *buffer[1024];
        unsigned int len=0;

        len=[(NSInputStream *)stream  read:buffer maxLength:1024];
        if(len>0){  
            @try{
                [data appendBytes:&buffer length:len];
            }
            @catch(NSException *ex){
                NSLog(@"Fail: %@", ex); 
            }
            [statusLabel setText:[data stringValue]];
            //[bytesRead setIntValue:[bytesRead intValue]+len];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"No Buffer");
        }
        break ;
    }
```

Comment: +1 nice, specific question, with a code sample... makes it easy and fun for folks to help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

declare your buffer as:

```
uint8_t buffer[1024];
```

and do the append as:

```
[data appendBytes:buffer length:len];
```

Comment: I think the only difference between your code and mine is the "&" before the buffer object in the appendBytes call. Am I missing something else? I have tried this both ways, and the same thing happens.

Comment: OIC! I got it. Thanks very much. Now just have to figure out how to convert the byte array to NSString. Thanks much!!

Comment: Look into [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] and release it when you are done.

Comment: Boot,

Can you expand on that a little. I have tried this:

NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]

but 'string' yields a nil value.

Answer (score 10):

This is a problem down at the C level: you're confused about buffers and pointers.

This code:

```
uint8_t *buffer[1024];
```

gives you a stack buffer of 1024 pointers to `uint8_t`s, which is almost certainly not what you want. Instead:

```
uint8_t buffer[1024];
```

Later on, you're passing the address of your pointer on the stack to -[NSMutableData appendBytes:length:], which again is not what you want: as in [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutabledata_Class/Reference/NSMutableData.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableData/appendBytes:length:), pass the first element:

```
[data appendBytes:buffer length:len];
```

There's a [very thorough programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/ReadingInputStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002273-1001882) with complete code for what you're trying to do, you may want to reference it.

As for `__TERMINATING_DUE_TO_UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTION__`, memory corruption and bad pointer dereferencing isn't something you can catch with an Objective-C `@try`/`@catch`; it's much lower-level. On the other hand, you can still catch this in the debugger if you turn debugging on.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. Being a PC (vb and .net) programmer, you could imagine how this could be overwhelming to a 3-day XCode programmer. :) Its very refresging to get a detailed, non-snobby answer. :) When i get the rep I will vote up your answers.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness `read:maxLength:` returns an NSInteger and will be negative if there was an error. Assigning it to an unsigned int discards this and can cause a crash.